# Преобразование списка в множество без упорядочивания

Tags: python, сортировка, list, set

На входе имеется список

```
my_list = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0]
```

При преобразовании в множество получаем:

```
my_set = set(my_list)
>>> my_set = {0, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}
```

Есть ли способ обойти это?

Comment: а что должен дать вам метод `set()`, если у вас нет повторяющихся элементов? можно циклом дополнять множество

Comment: Увы, тот же результат
'result_set = set()
for i in result:
result_set.add(i)
print(result_set)
>>> my_set = {0, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
 my_set = sorted(set(my_list), key=my_list.index)
```

Вообще set это несортированная коллекция уникальных элементов. В вашем случае просто так совпало. Для ускорения поиска и других операций элементы в множестве располагаются определённым образом.

Comment: Согласен, но sorted() возвращает list

Comment: Как уже сказано, нельзя задать порядок на множестве. Другими словами нельзя повлиять на то как Питон хранит элементы в множестве. Думаю вам нужно выбрать другой тип данных для решения вашей задачи.

Answer (score 4):

Множество **по определению** есть **неупорядоченным**, значит, это просто неправильный подход.
Не возможно полагаться на порядок элементов в множестве.

Как я понял, вы хотите просто устранить дубликаты с сохранением порядка:

```
new_list = []

for el in my_list:
    if el not in new_list:
        new_list.append(el)
```